# Как переопределить свойство другого класса?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Пишу десктопное приложение на *PyQt5*, используя *Qt Designer*.

Файл **uidesign.py**, который содержит разметку:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Взаимодействие с БД. [NORMAL USER]"))
```

И файл **main.py**, содержащий логику взаимодействия виджетов:

```
import sys
from uidesign import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3 as lite
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QMessageBox, QApplication
from uidesign import Ui_MainWindow


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):




def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() # Экземпляр класса Ui_MainWindow, в нем конструктор всего GUI.
        self.ui.setupUi(self) # Инициализация GUI
        self.myFunc()

    def myFunc(self):
        pass
```

В `myFunc(self)` я хочу написать функцию, которая будет изменять имя окна в зависимости от нужд.

Как мне правильно унаследовать мой **uidesign.py** и выполнить обращение к нужному методу, чтобы я мог изменить имя окна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
#from uidesign import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3 as lite
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QMessageBox, QApplication
#from uidesign import Ui_MainWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(219, 62)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Взаимодействие с БД. [NORMAL USER]"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "click me"))



class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() # Экземпляр класса Ui_MainWindow, в нем конструктор всего GUI.
            self.ui.setupUi(self)     # Инициализация GUI

            self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Напишите здесь новое имя окна")

            self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myFunc)

            self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
            self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.ui.pushButton)

    def myFunc(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.lineEdit.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = MyWin()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо.